# format() function generates scientific number in jupyter

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I am trying to check the maximum per feature with following code, but it generates scientific number. However, `format()` function should generate decimal or float as far as i know. What is wrong with my code?

`Input : print("Cancer data per-feature maxima:\n{}".format(cancer.data.max(axis=0)))`

```
[2.811e+01 3.928e+01 1.885e+02 2.501e+03 1.634e-01 3.454e-01 4.268e-01
 2.012e-01 3.040e-01 9.744e-02 2.873e+00 4.885e+00 2.198e+01 5.422e+02
 3.113e-02 1.354e-01 3.960e-01 5.279e-02 7.895e-02 2.984e-02 3.604e+01
 4.954e+01 2.512e+02 4.254e+03 2.226e-01 1.058e+00 1.252e+00 2.910e-01
 6.638e-01 2.075e-01]
```

Comment: I suspect you have a misunderstanding of what "float" or "decimal" mean. `format` always generates a string.

Comment: Sometimes that string may include scientific notation representations of numbers. This is normal and expected behavior.

Comment: The numpy array display is scientific because values range from 2501 to 0.02.  Scientific notation lets it show similar levels of precision across the whole numeric range.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, scientific notation is a valid format for floats, so you might be misunderstanding that a little, though it might be just language misunderstanding. Second of all, you're not printing a float but a numpy array, so what gets displayed has less to do with the `format()` function and more to do with the way the `__str__` function is implemented in `numpy.ndarray`.

To get the result you're probably looking for, i.e. suppress scientific notation, putting following line before your print (or rather at the beginning of your script, 1 call should suffice for the whole execution of your program) should result in the result you're looking for.

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```